# Как разбить на паги?

Tags: файлы, php

Всем привет. Помогите, как разбить такую вещь на паги? Очень нужно!

```
$filelogchat = file( 'f_say.dat' );
foreach($filelogchat as $logchat ){
  $string=explode("   ",$logchat);
  $nabo= $nabo+1;
}
for($si=sizeof($filelogchat)-1;$si+1>sizeof($filelogchat)-$nabo; $si--)
{
  $string=explode("   ",$filelogchat[$si]);
  echo $string[0].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Какие паги? о_О

Comment: >Какие ещё паги?

видимо, это от слова Page. Вероятно, автору это кажется очень остроумным. Хотя, мне случалось слышать, как кто-то вместо "фреймворк" говорил "фрамуга", считая, что это крутое слово из арсенала кулхацкера

Comment: @dreamchild, За "фрамугу" спасибо ))))

Comment: Фрамуга - ОГОНЬ! нужно тег сделать!

Comment: @Филипп Синкевич, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$x = explode("   ",file_get_contents('f_say.dat')); //загрузка и разбор данных
$per_page = 10;                             //значений на странице
$p = (int)$_GET['p'];                       //тут может быть warning, поставить @ )
$total_p = (int)(count($x) / $per_page);        //страниц всего 
$p = $p > $total_p ? $total_p : $p;         //проверка не несуществующую страницу
$p = $p < 0 ? 0 : $p;

for($i=$p*$per_page;$i<$p*$per_page+$per_page; $i++) {  // Вывод стриницы
    if (isset($x[$i])) {  //проверка записи (последняя страница неполная)
        print $x[$i]."<br>";                            //вывод строки
    }
}

print "<br>Страницы: ";                             //вывод пагера
for($i=0;$i<=$total_p; $i++) {
    print "<a href='?p=$i'>".($i+1)."</a>&nbsp;";   // если вместо i+1 сделать i, страницы будут идти с 0ля.
}
?>
```

Comment: зачем так?

>$p = (int)$_GET['p']; //тут может быть warning, поставить @ )

проще

>if (isset($_GET['p']))$p = (int)$_GET['p'];  else $p=0;

##

и 

>for($i=$p*$per_page;$i<$p*$per_page+$per_page; $i++)

Вот это называется нагрузка на цикл! каждая итерация делает еще кучу действий, хотя этого не нужно, ранее нужно все переменные сделать и отослать циклу, иначе в дальнейшем это будет каша и оптимизировать удастся с трудом, т.к. ошибок не будет, но код изначально плох, очень плох.

\+ ко всему **{** это лишний синтаксис как в условии так и в цикле.
и зачем тут вообще 2 цикла,нужен то всего один

Comment: Зачем так?
$p = (int)$_GET['p']; //тут может быть warning, поставить @ )
Чтоб не делать IF

Про нагрузку на цикл не знаю. Почитаю конечно - не думал что внутренний оптимизатор настолько плохо сделан, что не может сам предварительно вычислить это и подставить константу. Вроде это основы компиляторов и они уже это делали 80х годах.

2 цикла - 1й для вывода линий с текстом, а 2й для вывода пагера (1 2 3 4)

{ как раз для того чтобы новенькому было туда легко чтото добавлять и удалять

Так что все Ваши замеяания делаю с учетом своих соображений с точностью наоборот ))

Comment: спасибо , очень выручил , сейчас взакладках сохраню))